# Can't add VLAN in the "allowed VLAN"

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, trunk

Why is this command not accepted?

```
switchport trunk allowed vlan add 52,160,176,177,247
```

I tried adding only one VLAN; it's also not accepted. No error is shown or anything; it's just not showing when I do `show run int [interface id]`. I have the following configuration. This will be used for an Access Point, just to allow certain VLANs on this port. What could I be missing or could this be an iOS bug?

```
Switch Model: WS-C3560-24PS
IOS Version: C3560 Software (C3560-IPBASEK9-M), Version 12.2(55)SE4, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
 
interface FastEthernet0/22
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 247
 switchport mode trunk
 spanning-tree portfast trunk
end
 
show int fa0/22 shows that allowed vlan are still showing "ALL".

Switch#sh int fa0/22 switchport
Name: Fa0/22
Switchport: Enabled
Administrative Mode: trunk
Operational Mode: down
Administrative Trunking Encapsulation: dot1q
Negotiation of Trunking: On
Access Mode VLAN: 1 (default)
Trunking Native Mode VLAN: 247 
Administrative Native VLAN tagging: enabled
Voice VLAN: none
Administrative private-vlan host-association: none
Administrative private-vlan mapping: none
Administrative private-vlan trunk native VLAN: none
Administrative private-vlan trunk Native VLAN tagging: enabled
Administrative private-vlan trunk encapsulation: dot1q
Administrative private-vlan trunk normal VLANs: none
Administrative private-vlan trunk associations: none
Administrative private-vlan trunk mappings: none
Operational private-vlan: none
Trunking VLANs Enabled: ALL
Pruning VLANs Enabled: 2-1001
Capture Mode Disabled
Capture VLANs Allowed: ALL
```

Comment: Please use the Preformatted-text option (`{}`) rather than trying to format the text with HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to already have a VLAN in the allowed list (not "all") before you can use the add command to append to the existing list.

So, first, use: `switchport trunk allowed vlan 52`

Then you can use: `switchport trunk allowed vlan add 160,176,177,247`

The reason being, right now it's set to "all", so there's nothing to add since they're all already allowed.  That's why you have to limit it to just 1 or more (but not "all") vlan(s) at first and then add to it after the fact.

Alternatively, you can set the VLAN allowed list with multiple VLANs in a single command by simply not using the "add" keyword in what you were already attempting, such as: `switchport trunk allowed vlan 52,160,176,177,247`.

Comment: I do, those VLAN I'm adding are vlans that I already created or existing. Sh vlan br

VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------
1    default                          active      
52                   active    
160                          active    
176                   active    
177                                   active    
247                    active

Comment: @BehindTheWall That's not what I was saying. I know you have the VLANs created on the switch. I'm saying you have to have your trunk port limited to a single VLAN before you can add more VLANs to its allowed list.  Right now you have it set to allow "all" VLANs, so there's nothing to "add" (that's like saying infinity+1).

Comment: @BehindTheWall, you are trying to add VLANs to a trunk that already has those VLANs in the list. If you remove the `add` keyword, then you simply set the allowed VLANs on the trunk to those in your command. You only use the `add` keyword to add VLANs to an already restricted list. The default list is all VLANs, so the `add` keyword does nothing. Leaving out the `add` keyword will simply restrict the trunk to those VLAN in the command.

Comment: Okay now it worked. I tried adding vlan 52 first on the allowed vlan. Then adding the rest of the vlan works as well. I know I tried adding vlan 52 last time which did not show at all. Anyways its working. Thank you!

Comment: @RonMaupin Yep.  That's what I was trying to say but couldn't think of how to word it differently.

Comment: I see that maybe what I did last time I added the command "add" instead of just "switchport trunk allowed vlan 52". thank you for clarifying that

Answer (score 0):

Please add new vlan ids to existing vlans on trunk interface
For example

```
#interface ethernet 1/20
#switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,40
#switchport mode trunk
#no shutdown
```

For above senario for example if we want to add additional new vlan 60 to existing trunk interface then executive command

```
#int ethernet 1/20
#switchport trunk allowed vlan add 60
#no shut down
```

Then save configuration from running configure to startip config

```
#copy running-config startup-config
```

Then check again your config

```
#sh run
```

It should be

```
#int ethernet 1/20
#switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,40,60
#switchport mode trunk
#no shutdown
```